# Details about windows phone 8 app development / kick starting windows phone 8 app development ? ?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1.1

I am new to windows phone 8 development , i would like to know the following things from you all :-

1)System requirements for windows phone 8 development ?

2)Along with vs2012 do i require any other Tools for windows phone 8 development ?

3)Official download link for windows phone 8 SDK ?

3)I am developing an app , i would like to target all devices (windows phone 7 and windows phone 8) , using windows phone 8 sdk is it possible to do so ?

4)Where can i get some good resources for learning windows phone 8 development ?

Thanks in Adavnce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)

System Requirements

**Supported operating systems**

- Windows 8 (x64)

**Supported architectures**

- 64-bit (x64)

**Hardware requirements**

- 1.6 GHz or faster processor
- 4 GB of RAM
- 4 GB of available hard disk space
- List item

**Windows Phone 8 Emulator**

- Windows 8 Pro edition or greater
- Requires a processor that supports Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)

If your computer meets the hardware and operating system requirements, but does meet the requirements for the Windows Phone 8 Emulator, the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 will install and run. However, the Windows Phone 8 Emulator will not function and you will not be able to deploy or test apps on the Windows Phone 8 Emulator.
Notes
To start Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone, click the application in the Apps list. If you have Visual Studio Professional, Premium or Ultimate installed on the computer, the Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone shortcut won't appear. Instead, start your Visual Studio instance as usual and then create Windows Phone SDK 8.0 projects using the installed Windows Phone templates.
If you try to run a project in Windows Phone Emulator and Hyper-V is not enabled, you will be prompted to turn on Hyper-V. Turning on Hyper-V requires you to restart your computer.

2)No other tools is needed for Windows Phone 8 Development.
Blend for Windows Phone is included in the Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone

3) [SDK download](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-phone#product-express-phone-requirements)

4) No, app created using Windows Phone 8 SDK will only target Windows Phone 8. you would need to target Windows Phone 7.5 in order to capture both 7.5 and 8.

5) There are plenty of resources around MSDN